Setting the x-position of violin plots in Seaborn
I have some code that creates a violin plots (with 10 violins) using Seaborn:
sns.violinplot(data=chain[:, -10:], ax=ax, inner=None, linewidth=1)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(10))  # Adds spacing between violins
ax.set_xticklabels([f"{i}" for i in range(10)])

which is almost what I want. Currently it plots the x positions of each violin as 0, 1, 2, 3...
But I want to set my own x axis values for the horizontal positions of the violins. Something like my own list: [1.6, 2.5, 6.9,...]
Is it possible to do this?

Did you find useful one of the answer or you found a better solution?

sns.violinplot returns the axes where it is drawn so you can use it to modify the plot as you wish. Below an example with Titanic data:
ax = sns.violinplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", inner=None, linewidth=1)
myxticks = [16, 25, 69]
ax.set_xticks(myxticks) 
ax.set_xticklabels([f"{i}" for i in myxticks])
plt.show()



(As you didn't provide test data nor fully reproducible code, I hope I understood your question well. If not, please add missing information.)
In the latest seaborn versions (as of 0.13.0), many functions have a new parameter, native_scale. When set to True, the violins will be positioned numerically instead of the default categorical positions (0, 1, 2, ...).
The data needs to be a "long form" dataframe, which can be easily constructed from the givens.
The widths of the violins is similar to a categorical plot, but scaled by the distance of the x positions which are nearest to each other.
Here is an example:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xs = [1.6, 2.5, 6.9, 10.7, 12.9, 16.4, 18.5, 19.9, 22.3, 23.9]
chain = np.random.normal(0.01, 1, size=(1000, 10)).cumsum(axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.repeat(xs, chain.shape[0])
df['values'] = chain[:, -10:].T.flatten()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12, 6))

sns.violinplot(data=chain[:, -10:], ax=ax1, inner=None, linewidth=1)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(xs)), xs)

sns.violinplot(data=df, x='x', y='values', hue='x', palette='tab10',
               native_scale=True, orient='vertical', inner=None, linewidth=1)
ax2.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
ax2.set_xticks(xs)

sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


